# How to configure standard tokenizer in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a multi language data set and a Standard analyzer that takes care of the tokenizing for this data set very nicely. The only bad part is that it removes the special characters like @, #, :, etc.. Is there any way that I can use the standard tokenizer and still be able to search on the special characters?

I have already looked into combo analyzer plugin which did not work as I had hoped.Apparently the combination of analyzers do not work in a chain like the token filters. They work independently which is not useful for me.
 Also I looked into the char mapping filter in order to process the data before tokenizing it, but it does not work like the word delimiter token filter where we can specify "type_table" to convert a special character into an ALPHANUM. It just maps one word to another word. As a result I won't be able to search on the special characters.
Also, I have looked into the pattern analyzers, which would work for the special characters but they are not recommended for a multi language data set.

Can anybody point me in the right direction in order to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you still want to use the standard tokenizer, I thing the most possible way it doing mapping special chars to some words in char_filter level. e.g. you can map "@" ==> "symbol_at", "#" ==> "symbol_sharp", ... then it will be keep by standard tokenizer

Comment: @Duc.Duong ...how can i bring back my special characters after standard tokenizer step without disturbing others.

Comment: Can you explain more about the purpose to bring it back ?

Comment: @Duc.Duong if i don't then i miss special characters which i cannot search right.?

Comment: If your search use same analyzer, or use same char_filter then you can search it. Because it'll generate same tokens.

Comment: @Duc.Duong...it would give wrong search results if i search for "symbol_at"...returns a match though its not part of indexed text.

Comment: You can choose another map depend on your data, e.g. `_at_sign_`, users will never input such text for searching